# MS access reference

Tags: outlook, reference

I am creating an Outlook Automation App using Ms Access. My question is: Is it possible to add references during runtime? How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, instead of saying

```
new Outlook.Application
```

Say

```
CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

This switches it from early binding to late binding.  A little slower, but it will work fine.

If you want intellisense to work properly, use early binding (the first form) while you are coding, and then switch it to late binding (the second form) when you are done.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the help.. Thats really nice!! It works now without adding the reference in the design time.. Thanks